# Using D3 requests (json) over SSL with path url gives Mixed Content error?

Tags: javascript, json, ssl, d3.js

I'm not sure what's going on here - but I thought I'd ask the crowd. Basically I have a fetch JSON data function with D3 that's working on my local development server, but when I move it to production (which is hosted over SSL), I get the following error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://myapp.com/path/to/mydata/'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

It works fine over plain HTTP. The thing is, I'm not specifying a scheme or even an endpoint, I'm just using an absolute path from the root of the web server as follows:

```
var url = '/path/to/mydata/'
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {
    // do something with data
});
```

Is there anyway I can force this to use SSL? Something similar to `"//cdn.com/path/to/asset.js"` where the scheme is omitted to allow for both SSL and plain HTTP requests to be made depending on the content of the server.

**Updates**

More information: I'm hosting this on Heroku, and other requests to my API seem to be working just fine including those using `d3.csv` and `jQuery.get`.

Comment: I really don't want to have to change the endpoint location for both production and development. So help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why D3 is insisting on plain http in this case. As a workaround, you could simply detect the protocol and adjust the url accordingly:

```
var url = window.location.protocol + '//path/to/mydata/'
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {
    // do something with data
});
```

Comment: One other thought - I believe D3 uses jQuery's ajax functions. Have you tried upgrading your version of jQuery?